# How to get objects to shoot in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm just updating as my code has changed, but my new question is, how would I allow the bullet to shoot out of the player wherever it may be when the space bar is pressed. Because right now I'm trying to set the spawn location of the bullet to be wherever the player is at at the game, but I don't know how.

Here is the updated code:

```
import pygame, random, sys
import random
import os

from pygame.locals import *

WINDOWWIDTH = 600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 40

ROBOTMINSIZE = 50
ROBOTMAXSIZE = 50
ROBOTMINSPEED = 1
ROBOTMAXSPEED =1
ADDNEWROBOTRATE = 3
ADDNEWBULLETRATE = 3


PLAYERMOVERATE = 1

#pregame information and questions

print('''Hello There! Welcome to my Machine Domination Game! First you will be given information about Machine Domination. If you answer the question correctly, you will be allowed to play a game!
         The informatiion is printed below. Memorize it, and when you are ready, you will be asked a question.

         Machine Domination, also known as AI takeover, efers to a hypothetical scenario in which artificial intelligence (AI) becomes the dominant form of intelligence on Earth, with computers or
         robots effectively taking control of the planet away from the human race. Possible scenarios include a takeover by a superintelligent AI and the popular notion of a robot uprising. As computer
         and robotics technologies are advancing at an ever increasing rate, AI takeover is a growing concern. It has also been a major theme throughout science fiction for many decades, though the scenarios
         dealt with by science fiction are generally very different from those of concern to scientists.

         There is an ongoing debate over whether or not artificial intelligence will pose a threat to the human race, or to humans' control of society. Some of the concerns are: the issue of feasibility
         (whether or not AI can reach human or better intelligence); whether or not such strong AI could take over (or pose a threat); and whether it would be friendly or unfriendly (or indifferent) to humans.
         The hypothetical future event in which strong AI emerges is referred to as the technological singularity.


         Futurist and computer scientist Raymond Kurzweil has noted that "There are physical limits to computation, but they're not very limiting." If the current trend in computer computation improvement continues,
         and existing problems in creating artificial intelligence are overcome, sentient machines are likely to immediately hold an enormous advantage in at least some forms of mental capability, including the
         capacity of perfect recall, a vastly superior knowledge base, and the ability to multitask in ways not possible to biological entities. This may give them the opportunity to— either as a single being or as a
         new species — become much more powerful than humans, and to displace them.

         Stephen Hawkins also said that in 100 years AI could actually take over. We need to start acting now to stop Machine Domination!''')

questions=["What is AI takeover?", "How ling did Stephen Hawkins say before AI takes over?", "When do we need to start acting to stop AI takeover?"]
answers1=["AI takover is the idea that robots will take over Earth.", "AI takeover os the idea that robots will be made in 100 years."]
answers2=["100 years.", "1000 years."]
answers3=["Now.", "Later"]




advance=input("Press Enter for question.")
number=(random.randint(0,2))

if number==0:
    print(questions[0])
    print("1 " + answers1[0] + " " + "2 " + answers1[1])
    user=input("Type 1 or 2 for your answer")
    if user=='1':
        print("Correct!")
    elif user=='2':
        print("Sorry, wrong answer.")
        os._exit(0) 

elif number==1:
    print(questions[1])
    print("1 " + answers2[0] + " " + "2 " + answers2[1])
    user2=input("Type 1 or 2 for your answer")
    if user2=='1':
        print("Correct!")
    elif user2=='2':
        print("Sorry, wrong answer.")
        os._exit(0) 

elif number==2:
    print(questions[2])
    print("1 " + answers3[0] + " " + "2 " + answers3[1])
    user3=input("Type 1 or 2 for your answer")
    if user3=='1':
        print("Correct!")
    elif user3=='2':
        print("Sorry, wrong answer.")
        os._exit(0)



def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                    terminate()
                return
def playerHasHitRobot(playerRect, robots):
    for b in robots:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
    return False




def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))

pygame.display.set_caption('Shooter')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

# set up fonts

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up sounds
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('invasion.wav')
deathSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('explosion.wav')

# set up images
playerImage = pygame.image.load('earth.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
robotImage = pygame.image.load('robot.png')
background_image=pygame.image.load("space.png").convert()
bullet_image = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")


# show the "Start" screen
drawText('Welcome to my game.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()


topScore = 0
while True:
    # set up the start of the game
    robots = []
    bullets = []
    score = 0
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    robotAddCounter = 0
    bulletAddCounter = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while True: # the game loop runs while the game part is playing
        score += 1 # increase score
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                    bulletAddCounter += 1
                    if bulletAddCounter == ADDNEWBULLETRATE:
                        bulletAddCounter = 0
                        bulletSize = 10
                        newBullet= {'rect': pygame.Rect(20, 20, 20, 20),
                                    'speed': 12,
                                    'surface':pygame.transform.scale(bullet_image, (bulletSize, bulletSize)),
                                        }
                        bullets.append(newBullet)




            if event.type == KEYUP:

                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()

                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False



            robotAddCounter += 1
            if robotAddCounter == ADDNEWROBOTRATE:
                robotAddCounter = 0
                robotSize = random.randint(ROBOTMINSIZE, ROBOTMAXSIZE)
                newRobot= {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-robotSize), 0 - robotSize, robotSize, robotSize),
                            'speed': random.randint(ROBOTMINSPEED, ROBOTMAXSPEED),
                            'surface':pygame.transform.scale(robotImage, (robotSize, robotSize)),
                            }
                robots.append(newRobot)



       #Move the player around.
        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)

        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)


    # Move the robots down.
        for b in robots:
            b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])

        for b in bullets:
            b['rect'].move_ip(40, 12)


            pygame.display.update()



     # Delete robots that have fallen past the bottom.
        for b in robots[:]:
            if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                robots.remove(b)    


        # Draw the game world on the window.
        windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)
        windowSurface.blit(background_image,[0,0])

        # Draw the score and top score.
        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, windowSurface, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, windowSurface, 10, 40)

        # Draw the player's rectangle
        windowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)

        # Draw each robot
        for b in robots:
            windowSurface.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])
        for b in bullets:
            windowSurface.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])


        pygame.display.update()

# Check if any of the robots have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitRobot(playerRect, robots):
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score # set new top score
            break

        mainClock.tick(FPS)





    # Stop the game and show the "Game Over" screen.
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    gameOverSound.play()

    drawText('GAME OVER', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()

    gameOverSound.stop()
```

The main part that I've been trying to change is this:

```
# Move the robots down.
        for b in robots:
            b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])

        for b in bullets:
            b['rect'].move_ip(40, 12)


            pygame.display.update()
```

I've been trying to set the location of the bullet to wherever the player is at. Right now it is at 40 and 12. So how would i set it to that location. Also, how do i make it move straight up because right now it moves in a diagonal line. Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying execute your code but there are resources like videos or images that we don't have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw everything before

```
pygame.display.update()
```

(and after `windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)` )

Now you draw bullets after `update()` which sends everything from buffer to monitor (or rather to video card which draws it on monitor), and before `fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)` which clears buffer.

**EDIT:**

```
# --- drawing ---

... do not draw here ...

# clear buffer
windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)


... draw everything here ...


# send buffer to video card and on monitor/screen
pygame.display.update()

... do not draw here ...
```

Comment: before `pygame.display.update()` - see new code in may answer.

Comment: I did this, however for some reason, the bullet is not appearing.

Comment: now in your code you draw bullets **after** `update`. And after drawing bullets your loop returns to `fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)` and removes bullets from buffer before `update()` can send then on monitor.

Comment: So I'm supposed to draw bullets both before and after the update?

Comment: only "before" - if you draw anything "after" `update()` then `fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)` will remove it from buffer and you don't see it - you will only waist time.

Comment: Yes. I have done exactly that and the bullets are still not working. Everything else is drawn except the bullets.

Comment: so check bullets list - maybe it is empty or bullets are draw but not in screen area.

Comment: or create bigger bullets then 1x1 pixel.

Comment: OK so the bullet is working but there is a new problem, I cannot get he bullet to shoot out of the player to go straight up.

Comment: you have to change only `x` and you change  `x` and `y` - `move_ip(40, 12)` - read [Rect.move()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move)

Comment: btw: you could use class instead of dictionary for bullet information. and then you can add to class methods like `draw()`, `move()` or `update()`